# run thread from the class instance and also from the main

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to make following test program run:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo
{
    void t1()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            cout << "thread 1" << endl;
    }

    thread bar()
    {
        return thread(&foo::t1, this);
    }
};


void t2()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        cout << "main " << endl;
}


int main()
{
    foo inst;
    inst.bar();
    thread x(t2);

    return 0;
}
```

"thread 1" runs but application terminates when it's supposed to run thread "x"
output is:

> /home/user/dev/libs/llvm-3.4.2/bin/clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
>   -pthread main.cpp -o 'Application' ./'Application' terminate called without an active exception thread 1 thread 1 thread 1 thread 1 thread
>   1 make: *** [all] Aborted

the goal is to run 2 threads in the same time using an object instance within another function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join (or detach) the thread:

```
int main()
{
    foo inst;
    inst.bar();
    thread x(t2);

    x.join(); //<-------

    return 0;
}
```

otherwise you see abort.
Join will wait til the thread finishes.

Note that `bar` has returned you a thread which you haven't joined either which will give the same problem. Something like...

```
int main()
{
    foo inst;
    auto y = inst.bar();
    thread x(t2);
    x.join();
    if (y.joinable())
        y.join();
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to consider something like std::async instead.

Comment: I copied your "main" and replaced with mine and still the same error :(

Comment: @codekiddy See from "Note that..." You app aborts (by design) if you don't join (or detach) all the threads you kick off.

Comment: std::async FTW. Some interesting notes on it from Scott Meyers [here](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/stdfutures-from-stdasync-arent-special.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your *process* exits when the `main` function exits. You need to wait for the threads to finish ([joining them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)), or [detach them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) from the current process.

Comment: thanks, I joined the thread "x" before return, it still results in error, can you clarify your answer please?

Comment: Exiting `main` or calling `exit` destroys all threads, no matter whether they are detached. One can terminate the main thread though, so that it never leaves `main` and calls `exit`.